# simple question: in python3 env, why can't run simple print?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
print("hello", end="")
```

output:

```
[Running] python -u "/home/a/code/projects/project1.py"
  File "/home/a/code/projects/project1.py", line 1
    print("hello", end="")
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

settings.json

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pydocstyleEnabled": false,
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3.6"
}
```

been looking up about why code is being run on older version of python in vscode... can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're using Python 2:

```
Python 2.7.16 (default, Oct 10 2019, 22:02:15) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("hello", end="")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print("hello", end="")
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In Python3 it wouldn't happen:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("hello", end="")
hello>>>
```

Comment: thanks, already established that. And why does this error happen even when i selected my interpreter to run on the latest version of python?

Comment: Because you **didn't** actually select the latest version of Python (doh…) Why is it so, is not a matter of Python programming but of system administration - this question cannot be answered without knowing the details of your system platform, how you installed Python etc.